# Using .htaccess to prevent serialized objects in post / get requests

Tags: .htaccess, serialization, request, http-post, http-get

Is there an option to prevent serialized objects in post / get requests (from input fields) via .htaccess?

Comment: And how to identify serialized objects in an URL?

Comment: That's a good question indeed! My initial question aims at XSS and ways to prevent it on a "lower level".